# json lot loading via ajax on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am a newbie to jQuery and ajax. I am creating an app where different content is loaded from the same json file depending on navigation option clicked.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $wrapper = $(".wrapper");
    $(document).on("click", ".navLink", loadRecipes);
    function loadRecipes(){

        var type = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "recipes.json", 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.recipes.length; i++){

                var recipe = data.recipes[i];
                if(type == recipe.type){

                    var name = "<h3 class='recipeTitle'>" + recipe.name + "</h3>";
                    $wrapper.append(name);

                }

            }

        });
        return false;

    }

})
```

And the json looks something like:

```
{
"recipes":[
{"name": "A", "type":"type1"},
{"name": "B", "type":"type2"},
{"name": "C", "type":"type2"},
{"name": "C", "type":"type1"}
]
}
```

The href attribute matches the type attribute in the json file.
So specific elements of the json are loaded when clicking on a specific link.
When I first click on one of the links, appropriate content loads.
But when I try to click another link, the click event fires, but json content is not loaded.
I have introduced event delegation on the click event but it didn't help.
I thought it might be a problem with caching so I have added the cache: false parameter, but it also didn't help.
If anyone can give me a clue what might I be missing, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Are you sure `.wrapper` element exists all the time? I mean you said navigation.. So its unsure that element exists or not.. Alongside, you can try placing `debugger`  within `success` to see whether 2nd click comes to the place where expected..

Answer (score 0):

You take the same content from the same link, that why Ajax not loaded twice.
Perhaps will be suitable for you something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $wrapper = $(".wrapper");
$(document).on("click", ".navLink", loadRecipes);
function loadRecipes(){

    var type = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "recipes.json?type=" + type, 
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            var recipe = data;
            var name = "<h3 class='recipeTitle'>" + recipe.name + "</h3>";
                $wrapper.append(name);

        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

})

Change server answer depends type variable. The answer will be only you need data:

```
{"name": "B", "type":"type2"}
```

Or you can set Ajax only once on any event to get all types and on click just append it to wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Indira, thank you very much for your help. I have tried using your solution, but it didn't work. However what you had written "You take the same content from the same link" got me thinking- I had tried separating different data types into separate json files, but that still didn't work. I had however noticed that in the network tab in developer tools the appropriate files were loading when clicking on the links. Actually the html that I was loading into the $(".wrapper") was much more complicated- I had simplified it because it was not relevant when explaining my problem. The resulting elements took a lot more space on the page. And I feel a little bit silly, but I have then noticed that the new content was actually loading but just on the bottom of the page, the old content remained on the top. The solution to the problem is to just empty the $(".wrapper") at the top of the success response function.